# How to select same object twice in Django ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200 ,null=False)
class Profile(models.Model):
    food_selected_today = models.ManyToManyField(Food,related_name = 'inventory')
```

Now in profile model I want to have one food with same id for example Apple more than one time in food_selected_today. If I now add same food twice it only shows one Item. How can I add one food many times here.
Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is not possible natively with the built in relationship fields, but you can use your own `through`-model to give you the opportunity to have a `count` attribute for each relation:

```py
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

class Profile(models.Model):
    food_selected_today = models.ManyToManyField(Food, 
                                                 related_name='inventory', 
                                                 through='ProfileFood')

class ProfileFood(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```